# How can I switch between Google Chrome windows, including minimized ones, on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, window

On OS X apps I can switch between apps using <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>.

And I can switch between multiple "normal" windows of an app using <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd>.

I know that switching between full-screen Chrome windows is special and requires going left and right through virtual desktops, which can be done in several ways.

But what about when I have several Google Chrome windows, some of which are minimized to the dock, and some of which are not - none of the above methods includes those windows? Do I need a *fourth* way to access those?

Comment: Cmd + ` is the shortcut for juggling windows on Mac.

Comment: @Kushagra: Yes, as I mention in my second sentence. Try it with an app with at least one minimized windows though and you'll see you can't access that one.

Comment: I just managed to find [pretty much the same question over on **Ask Different**](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/77107/) even though I couldn't find it in my research before asking my own question here.

Answer (score 0):

ctrl + downward arrow works fine. It shows all the opened windows and the minimized ones in the bottom. ctrl + upward arrow shows all the opened application os your desktop.